# iOS: Should I create my buttons through programming or use images

Tags: ios, image, scaling

I've a few images that are rounded, dark borders and have white text in the middle of it. Should I use images or should I create these buttons by programming?

I'm not a 100% certain what is the best practice in this scenario.

**Edit:** There is only a few images that would support this.

Comment: What do you mean by pragmatically?

Comment: Create the radius, background color, etc through programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its all up to you, how you prefer to do that but as my opinion you need to create button programmatically and assign corner radius and shadow if your button's widths is dynamic. other wise if your button width and height is fix then you can also use that image as a button.

you can set nice button by drag and drop in storyboard and set dynamic constraints then provide border and corner radius.

```
btn.layer.borderWidth = 1;
btn.layer.borderColor =[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
btn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
btn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
btn.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

For every image the size of your project is going to increase. In order to increase your audience scope you should attempt to keep any project as small as possible. Therefor, although this is sort of a preference call, I would highly recommend using built-in IOS classes for the UI and save the graphics and storage space for when you REALLY need/want it.

Answer (score 0):

- Drag and drop UIButton in your controller
- Set Background Color for them as required
- Set Centered title with white color
- Use setCornerRadius to round them
- And set border Color while rounding.

**Sample Code :**

```
float cornerRadius = SCREEN_WIDTH*(47.f/320.f);
[[button layer] setCornerRadius:cornerRadius/2.f];
[button layer].borderWidth = 2;
[button layer].borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:100/255.0 green:175/255.0 blue:249/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
button.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
[button layoutIfNeeded];
```